# Separate Query for Count

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to get my query to grab multiple rows while returning the maximum count of that query.

My query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as Max FROM tableA LIMIT 0 , 30
```

However, it is only outputting 1 record.

I would like to return multiple record as it was the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Do I have to use separate queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use separate queries.

It's two separate pieces of information with different structures. One is a row set, the other is a single value. Trying to return both these pieces of information in one query, while possible, is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use a single query with the **SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS** function in it, with the use of LIMIT as well. So, while you run the first query through mysql_query(), you can then also run another query as:

```
mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
```

which will return you the number of total rows found through that query (no matter you use the LIMIT or not, SELECT FOUND_ROWS() will give you the result count without the LIMIT mentioned in your query).

Following is a sample query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_abc
```

Thanks